# efficient merge of arrays that contain overlapping values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Given a table with arrays of integers, the arrays should be merged so that all arrays that have overlapping entries end up as a single one.

Given the table `arrays`

```
     a      
------------
 {1,2,3}
 {1,4,7}
 {4,7,9}
 {15,17,18}
 {18,16,15}
 {20}
```

The result should look like this

```
{1,2,3,4,7,9}
{15,17,18,16}
{20}
```

As you can see duplicate values from a merged array may be removed and the order of the resulting entries in the array is unimportant. The arrays are integer arrays so functions from the `intarray` module can be used.

This will be done on a quite large table so performance is critical.

My first naive approach was to self-join the table on the `&&` operator. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT uniq(sort(t1.a || t2.a))
FROM arrays t1
JOIN arrays t2 ON t1.a && t2.a
```

This leaves two problems:

1. It is not recursive (it merges at most 2 arrays).
   This could probably be solved with a recursive CTE.
2. Merged arrays re-occur in the output.

Any input is very welcome.

Comment: This is not relational task, so SQL is not good language. Simple C code over sorted array should be best solution. This C extension should be really simple.

Comment: Since I always was interested in how postgres C extensions work I'll give this a try if nothing else comes up here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do $$
declare
    arr int[];
    arr_id int := 0;
    tmp_id int;
begin
    create temporary table tmp (v int primary key, id int not null);
    for arr in select a from t loop
        select id into tmp_id from tmp where v = any(arr) limit 1;
        if tmp_id is NULL then
            tmp_id = arr_id;
            arr_id = arr_id+1;
        end if;
        insert into tmp
            select unnest(arr), tmp_id
            on conflict do nothing;
    end loop;
end
$$;
select array_agg(v) from tmp group by id;
```

Comment: In the end a solution based on your ideas did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pure SQL version:

```
WITH RECURSIVE x (a) AS (VALUES ('{1,2,3}'::int2[]),
 ('{1,4,7}'),
 ('{4,7,9}'),
 ('{15,17,18}'),
 ('{18,16,15}'),
 ('{20}')
), y AS (
    SELECT 1::int AS lvl,
           ARRAY [ a::text ] AS a,
           a AS res
      FROM x
     UNION ALL
    SELECT lvl + 1,
           t1.a || ARRAY [ t2.a::text ],
           (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT unnest ORDER BY unnest)
              FROM (SELECT unnest(t1.res) UNION SELECT unnest(t2.a)) AS a) 
      FROM y AS t1
      JOIN x AS t2 ON (t2.a && t1.res) AND NOT t2.a::text = ANY(t1.a)
     WHERE lvl < 10
)
SELECT DISTINCT res
  FROM x
  JOIN LATERAL (SELECT res FROM y WHERE x.a && y.res ORDER BY lvl DESC LIMIT 1) AS z ON true
```